# Pyscript says that there is no directory but there is

Tags: python, html

im experiencing a frustrating problem where pyscript says that the directory doesnt exist. But it does. I have a file named 'pot1' and pyscript doesnt seem to see it.
Ive rewritten the directory over 893 times, and tried to search for the problem, ive written the directory to the file correctly.

```
<py-script>
    pot1 = open("C:/Plant Lab/sav/garden/pots/pot1", "r").readline()
</py-script>
```

But ive only gotten this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/lib/python3.10/_pyodide/_base.py", line 460, in eval_code
    .run(globals, locals)
  File "/lib/python3.10/_pyodide/_base.py", line 306, in run
    coroutine = eval(self.code, globals, locals)
  File "<exec>", line 1, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 44] No such file or directory: 'C:/Plant Lab/sav/garden/pots/pot1'
```

Ive tried searching on google, but only ended up on really basic answers like 'have you written the directory correctly?', I dont know what else to do. Ive tried using a \ instead of a /. Tried finding out what directory it is but CORS didnt let me. Meanwhile ill try again and again and again and again and again.

Comment: Speaking of basic answers, are you sure that the file is actually called "pot1"? Windows has a habit of hiding file extensions by default. Maybe your file has some extension like .txt for example?

Comment: try `os.listdir("C:/Plant Lab/sav/garden/pots/")`

Answer (score -1):

When using pyscript, the code is run in a virtual file system. If you run

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <py-script> import os;print(os.getcwd())</py-script>
  </body>
</html>
```

you should get `/home/pyodide`, which is the root dir of that virtual file system. Your folder and your file are not directly accessible through that virtual system (this is a limitation of Javascript applications).

The easiest way to access data from the file system is to use the `<py-config>` tag to fetch the file (more info [here](https://docs.pyscript.net/latest/tutorials/py-config-fetch.html)).

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <py-config> 
      [[fetch]] 
      files = ["/path/to/your/file"] </py-config>
    <py-script>
      pot1 = open("/path/to/your/file", "r").readline()
      print(pot1)
    </py-script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you update your file like this and try to access it, you will still have an error though. This is because the fetch method is usually used to load content from a remote server, but in your case, you could run a simple python web server by running

`python3 -m http.server`

and then access your page at http://0.0.0.0:8000/yourfile.html.

Comment: This does not change anything. The **virtual** file system of pyscript is not related with the file system of the OP.